# Output two dimensional array to csv file in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Given

`$a = (("a","b","c"),("d","e","f"))`

I want `$a` exported to a csv file like this

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
```

Something so simple seems tricky. What's the best way, my file will be less than 40 lines long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$a | % { $_ -join ','} |  out-file .\myfile.csv
```

Comment: Haha, yeah thanks. I'm just wondering why the Export-Csv only works with objects and not arrays.